# Programmatically load node edit form

Tags: nodes, forms, 8

I'm able to load node create forms like so

```
$node    = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create(['type' => 'avenue']);
$content = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node);

return $content;
```

However what if I want to load an edit form for a pre-existing node? I looked on this page https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/class/Node/8.2.x but I can't find anything that would relate to the edit form. Is there a way to load the edit form for a specific node?

Comment: Isn't it the same? As in, pass an existing `$node` object to `getForm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, on the linked page you would find `Node::load()` to get a pre-existing node:

```
$node    = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$content = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node);

return $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Controller -

```
if ($node) && !empty($node->id())) {
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($node->id());
  $build = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node);
  return $build;
}
else {
  return $this->redirect('node.add', ['node_type' => 'CONTENT_TYPE']);
}
```